# Questions on making a web API with sessions

Tags: rest, email, session, asp.net-web-api, password-less

I am attempting to make a website's back-end API (I want to make the back-end independent of the front-end so I'm only making a server-side API for now, abiding to RESTfulness as much as possible). I haven't done this before so I'm unaware of the 'best' & most secure way to do things.

**How I do it now:**

Some parts of the API should only be accessible to a specific user after they login and up to 24 hours later.

To do this, I am generating a random Session ID whenever a user logs in (I'm using passwordless logins so the user is assigned that ID when they click on a link in their email) on the server side, which respond by sending that session ID to the client once. The client then stores this session ID in localstorage (or a file in disk if the client is not a web browser).

Next, I store that ID along with the associated email in my DB (MySQL table) on the server side.

Now every time the client want something from my API, they have to provide the email & session ID in the URL (I don't want cookies for now), which the server checks against the ones in the DB, if they exist then the server responds fully else responds with an error.

After 24 hours, the server deletes the email/session ID pair and the user has to login again (to generate another session ID and associate it with their email).

**Now the questions:**

1. Is my method secure or does it have obvious vulnerabilities? Is
   there another battle-tested way I'm not aware of?
2. Is there a better way for the client to store the session ID (if
   they are a web browser)?
3. What is the best way to generate a unique session ID? Currently I
   generate a random 16-char string that I set as the primary key of
   the session-email table.
4. Is using a MySQL table the most performant/best way to store session
   IDs (given it will be queried with each request)?
5. Do I need to encrypt session IDs in any way? Is it secure for the
   client to send it as a 'naked' URL param?

Sorry for having too many questions in one post but I think they're related by the single scenario above. If it makes any difference, I'm using F# and I expect my client to either be an android app or a web app.

Comment: I am not sure what to do with your question. It is certainly not related to REST, it is just a regular web application. Please remove the REST tag, or explain what you did so far to make your API RESTful.

Comment: @inf3rno I mention REST at the beginning. Basically I want it to be a RESTful API (ie. I don't want the statefullness of my API to break REST).

Answer (score 0):

Your REST API MUST not know anything about the REST client session, not even the session id. If you don't want to send a password by every request, all you can do is signing the user id, and the timeout, so the service can authenticate based on the signature. Use JSON web token: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token

You can have a server side REST client, which can have the session your described. The question is, does it really worth the effort to develop a REST service instead of a regular web application? I am not sure in your case, but typically the answer is no, because you won't have any 3rd party REST client and your application does not have enough traffic to justify the layered architecture or it is not big enough to split into multiple processes, etc...

If security is important then you MUST use a true random generator algorithm or hardware. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#.22True.22_vs._pseudo-random_numbers It is not safe to send anything through HTTP, you must use HTTPS instead. You MUST use the standard Authorization header instead of a query param. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication